# Can't update the array defined with 'useState' in 'useEffect' hook in React-Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, hook

I have a `feedItems` array. I want to set this array's items according to `axios` get request's response. In the screen, I want to show the information of the elements of this array. So, before everything, I must set this array so that I will be able to show the info of elements of this array.

I have no problem while making an API request and I am sure that the `response.data` is not empty. However, when I use the `setFeedItems(...feedItems, response.data[i]);` function, I get the following error.

> [Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: Invalid attempt to spread non-iterable instance.]

Here is the code:

```
const [feedItems, setFeedItems] = useState([{}]);

  useEffect(async () => {
    console.log("here");
    let accessToken = await AsyncStorage.getItem("accessToken");
    const response = await axios
      .get(
        "http://repor****-env-1.eba-nj*******/feed",
        {
          headers: {
            Authorization: "Bearer " + accessToken,
          },
        }
      )
      .then((response) => {
        for (let i = 0; i < response.data.length; i++) {
          setFeedItems(...feedItems, response.data[i]);
        }

        //console.log(feedArray);
        console.log(feedItems);
      });
  }, []);
```

Comment: You haven't used `catch`  try using `catch` after `then` and if the problem still remains let know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you're spreading out `[{}]` into discrete arguments to `setFeedItems`. To **append** `response.data` to `feeditems`, you do this:

```
.then((response) => {
    setFeedItems(feedItems => [...feedItems, ...response.data]);
    // No `console.log(feedItems)` here, it will show you outdated information
});
```

Notice:

- Using the callback form, since you're updating state based on existing state, so you want to be sure to be using the up-to-date state.
- The `[]` around the return value so you're creating an array and spreading the items out into it.
- That it's spreading both the old `feedItems` and the new `response.data` out into that new array.

But if you want to **replace** `feedItems` with the data from `response.data` (which it looks like you probably do in this specific case), it's simpler:

```
.then((response) => {
    setFeedItems(response.data);
    // No `console.log(feedItems)` here, it will show you outdated information
});
```

Also, in the normal case, your `feedItems` would start out with an **empty** array, not an array with an empty object in it. So:

```
const [feedItems, setFeedItems] = useState([]);
```

---

Separately: `useEffect` won't do anything useful with the promise an `async` function returns (and does look at the return value, to see if it's a function), so you shouldn't pass an `async` function into it. Since you're already using explicit promise callbacks, there's no reason for the `await` and the `async` function. Also, you should handle promise rejection.

Putting all of that together (using the "replace" rather than "append" option):

```
const [feedItems, setFeedItems] = useState([{}]);

useEffect(() => {
    AsyncStorage.getItem("accessToken").
    then(accessToken => axios.get(
        "http://repor****-env-1.eba-nj*******/feed",
        {
            headers: {
            Authorization: "Bearer " + accessToken,
        },
    }))
    .then((response) => {
        setFeedItems(feedItems => [...feedItems, ...response.data]);
    })
    .catch(error => {
        // ...handle/report the fact an error occurred...
    });
}, []);
```

Live Example:

```js
const { useState, useEffect } = React;

// Mock `AsyncStorage`
const AsyncStorage = {
    getItem() {
        return Promise.resolve("some token");
    },
};

// Mock `axios`
const axios = {
    get() {
        return new Promise(resolve => {
            setTimeout(() => {
                resolve({data: [
                    {id: 1, text: "Item 1"},
                    {id: 2, text: "Item 2"},
                    {id: 3, text: "Item 3"},
                    {id: 4, text: "Item 4"},
                ]});
            }, 800);
        });
    },
};

const Example = () => {
    const [feedItems, setFeedItems] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        AsyncStorage.getItem("accessToken").
        then(accessToken => axios.get(
            "http://repor****-env-1.eba-nj*******/feed",
            {
                headers: {
                Authorization: "Bearer " + accessToken,
            },
        }))
        .then((response) => {
            setFeedItems(response.data);
        })
        .catch(error => {
            // ...handle/report the fact an error occurred...
        });
    }, []);

    return <div>
        <div>Item count: {feedItems.length}</div>
        {feedItems.map(({id, text}) => <div key={id}>{text}</div>)}
    </div>;
};

ReactDOM.render(<Example />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

Comment: I'd like to ask a question. Does the <View> I am returning render after this useEffect function?

Comment: @BilkentOgrencisi - Your component function is called initially on mount and renders the empty array, then the `useEffect` callback is run, and since it sets state that causes your component function to be called again, and it renders the array with item in it. The only way to avoid having that initial empty render is to move the code fetching the items into the parent compoent and not render this component at all until you have the items (which you'd pass as a prop).

Comment: I've updated the example above to show the number of items and to increase the "axios" delay, so you can see both renders occur in the example.

Comment: I have an additional question. Why don't we use the following code to set the array: ```setFeedItems(response.data)``` ?

Comment: @BilkentOgrencisi - That would be absolutely fine, if you want to *replace* the previous array with that data. In your example, it seems like you do, so that would be good. (In fact, you could say it's clearer.) I did the *append* option because it looked like you were doing that, but I think you're right we don't need to in this case.

Answer (score 3):

OK, there are a couple of issues with your code:

1. `useEffect` shouldn't use `async` functions. You should create an async function inside and call it there.
2. you are using `await` and `then`. Should stick to one.
3. you are actually adding a single element here `setFeedItems(...feedItems, response.data[i]);` instead of an array.

Try to use this
`setFeedItems([...feedItems, response.data[i]]);`

This will fix the error, but it won't fix your problem, as you are getting old `feedItem`.

Answer (score 1):

Why not updating the state with all the items inside `response.data` at once?
Instead of

```
for (let i = 0; i < response.data.length; i++) {
    setFeedItems(...feedItems, response.data[i]);
}
```

just do:

```
if (response.data.length) setFeedItems(prevState => [...prevState, ...response.data])
```